# Assigning values to Instance variables in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

The function I'm looking at:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"statedictionary" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    self.statesZips = dictionary;
    [dictionary release];

    NSArray *components = [self.stateZips allKeys];
    NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.States = sorted;

    NSString *selectedState = [self.states objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [stateZips objectForKey: selectedState];
    self.zips = array;  
}
```

Why is an NSDictionary allocated, then assigned to a pointer called *dictionary, and then assigned to the instance variable stateZips?   Why not allocate it and assign it directly to the instance variable and save memory of creating and releasing another NSDictionary?  The same methodology is always followed, including later in this function with the NSArray...

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.statesZips = dictionary;
[dictionary release];
```

Also, this sorting puts the keys from a hash table (dictionary) in alphabetical order.   I'm not sure I understand this line:

```
NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one seems to have addressed the fact that the line

```
self.statesZips = dictionary;
```

is not directly an instance variable assignment. `stateZips` is a property, and so that line of code calls the `setStateZips:` method. That method retains or copies the dictionary, so unless the `viewDidLoad` method intends to use it again for some purpose, it's not needed any longer. That makes it OK to `release` it.

The previous line:

```
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

allocates an object. That makes it your responsibility to `release` it once you don't need it any more. After assigning it to the `statesZips` property, it's no longer needed, so it's released and you shouldn't use `dictionary` any more. You'll notice that later code only refers to `self.stateZips`, not `dictionary`.

In the case of the `NSArray` later in the method, `viewDidLoad` does not allocate the object, so that method is not responsible for calling `release` on it. The rule of thumb is that if you `alloc` it, you're responsible for making sure it gets released. Otherwise, it's not your problem.

Sorting the array uses the `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method. A selector identifies a method in Objective-C. And the `@selector` is the literal syntax for selectors (kind of like how `@""` is the literal syntax for `NSString` objects). So, what that code says, is "give me an array where the objects in `components` are sorted, and use the `compare:` method to compare each object when you do the sort. When it sorts the array, it will call `compare:` on the objects in the array to determine how to put them in order.

Comment: I actually think that the retain/assign semantics of the statesZips property is irrelevant. The code allocates an object and so needs to release it, *regardless* of the semantics of statesZips, unless it's running in a garbage-collected environment.

Comment: @Barry Wark: well, no. the semantics of statesZips are very much relevant. if that method wouldn't retain the dictionary or copy it, accessing statesZip after line 7 would result in undefined behaviour (probably a segfault).

Comment: Convenience functions such as initWithContentsOfFile are autoreleased.

Comment: That's not correct. Initializers (like `initWithContentsOfFile:`) return objects that are not autoreleased. Convenience methods such as `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` are autoreleased.

Answer (score 4):

The `statesZips` property is probably retained, that's the reasoning.

When the NSDictionary is first allocated, its retain count is 1. When it's assigned to statesZips, the retain count becomes 2. When it's released, the retain count drops to 1, which is usually the desired outcome.

Note that the code below would have produced (almost) the same result:

```
self.statesZips = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

because `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` returns an autoreleased object.

As a convention, class methods like `[NSDictionary dictionary]` return autoreleased objects (which automatically get released after some time), while the usual alloc-init method (as in `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]`) return retained objects.

I suggest you read the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for further information.

**EDIT:** I must have missed the last part of your question when I first read it, but Barry has already answered that part.

Answer (score 2):

This code uses reference-counted memory management (not the automatic garbage collection memory management available in Objective-C 2.0 on OS X). When any object (in this case, the NSDictionary and the NSArray) are alloc'd, the caller is responsible for calling `-release` on that instance. Failing to call release causes a memory leak. The code could have been written as

```
self.statesZips = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] autorelease];
```

but at the expense of less explicit memory management (relying on `NSAutoreleasePool` to release the alloc'd instance at the end of the event loop iteration.

the call

```
[components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

returns an array of whose elements come from `components` but according to the return value of calling [elem1 compare:elem2] to compare two array elements.

Comment: +1 for the actual right answer to the question being asked.  The semantics of the statesZip property are irrelevant here.  The reason for the pattern is code legibility and explicit memory management as you described.  Thank Apple for ARC so that we'll get less and less of these questions going forward (I guess accessing block variable questions are the new retain/release questions)